# PHP MVC Basics for login form

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Im new to the forum and new to MVC.
I know the basics of PHP and have made a simple PHP website.
I now want to create a website that follows an MVC patter, atleast in its simplest form.

Would i be correct in assuming that, if for example we had a login for, the Model would contain the SQL select statements, the controller would handle the data e.g if (isset($_POST["username"])) { and the view would contain the basic HTML form where the user would enter the data?

Any information will be appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those assumptions are correct, I would recomend taking a look at an existing MVC framework such as [tinymv](http://www.tinymvc.com/) if you just want the MVC pattern or [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) if you want a bunch of other features as well . Then there are plenty of other alternatives.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Is there any major advantage in using the frameworks over just using my own folders for seperation?

Comment: I have personaly only used CakePHP and then as I say you get a ton of other feautures. But maybe the main advantage as a beginner is that the frameworks to some extent prevent you from cheating and breaking the pattern.